# how to recover a previous route name of page in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

for example I was on the home page, it has the route name "home", after I left on another page for example edit, how to get the name of the previous route on the edit page (here it is home)? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the referrer and try to "match" it with the routing service to see if a route exists for this path:

```
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer'); // get the referer, it can be empty!
    if (!\is_string($referer) || !$referer) {
        echo 'Referer is invalid or empty.';

        return;
    }

    $refererPathInfo = Request::create($referer)->getPathInfo();


    // try to match the path with the application routing
    $routeInfos = $this->router->match($refererPathInfo);

    // get the Symfony route name if it exists
    $refererRoute = $routeInfos['_route'] ?? '';
```

Check out [the full snippet on my blog](https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/snippets/get-the-routing-information-of-the-referer).

Comment: thank you it works, but after chanegr this line        $routeInfos = $this->router->match($refererPathInfo);        by this one       $routeInfos = $this->get('router')->match($refererPathInfo);

Comment: Yes, that depends on your controller setup. :)

Comment: is this variable accessible in all situations (web hosts, all servers, http / https)

Comment: I have this because I have injected the router service in the controller constructor. Check out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#constructor-injection

Comment: this variable referer, is accessible on all servers, even in https ?? because I saw on documentation that this variable is not guaranteed in all situations !!